# Display Ajax Response on div

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

How do I display ajax response on particular div? This statement worked `alert(data[i]['title']);` but I want to display on div. thanks

```
<td><a onclick="ajax_request('{% url recommendation id=track.id %}');" href="#"> Click Here</a></td>
```

Ajax Function

```
function ajax_request(url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'},
        success: function(data) {
                for(i=0;i<=data.length;i++){
                    alert(data[i]['title']); 
               }
            }
    })
}
```

View

```
@login_required
def recommendation(request, id):
    if request.is_ajax() and request.method == 'POST':
        track = Track.objects.get(pk=id)
        recommend = Song.objects.filter(title__icontains=track.title)[:5]
        results = []
        for data in recommend:
            results.append({'title': data.title})
        json = simplejson.dumps(results)
        return HttpResponse(json, mimetype="application/json")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, depending if you already have a div you want to display the content in or you create a new one with jQuery:

Existing one with id `myDiv`:

```
$('#myDiv').html(data[i]['title']);  //also $('#myDiv').text(data[i]['title']) possible
```

Create new div:

```
$('<div/>').html((data[i]['title']);
```

Comment: I've added `$('#myDiv').html(data[i]['title']);` and getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined`

Comment: If you can alert your `data[i]['title']` then you should be able to write it to a div as well. Check again if your alert really "alerts" your title and not something else like "undefined".

Comment: Another comment, your for loop should be `for(i=0;i<data.length;i++)`. If you use `<=` the last element will not exist (since index start at `0`). This last element is undefined. I guess this is where the error comes from.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your onsuccess event like this

```
 $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'},
            success: function(data) {
               for(i=0;i<=data.length;i++)
               $('#div').html(data[i]['title']);//Your success msg

                }
        });
```